# How to convert Directory Folders and Files to json string

Tags: winforms, json.net

I am working on Windows Form and I want to convert Directory Folders and Files to Json string like below,I am using newton json and have a json string like below with multiple Folders and Files , dynamic.

```
{
    "folder": {
        "name": "abc",        
        "folders": {
            "folder": {
                "name": "child abc",                
                "folders": {
                 "folder": {
                    "name": "child abcd"
                           }          
                           },
                "assets": {}
            }
        },
        "assets": {
            "asset": {
                "folder_id": 14,
                "uploaded_file": {
                    "content_type": "image/png",
                    "filename": "settings.png",
                    "file_data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAABsVJREFUeNrEV29"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
The Classes i am using are below mentioned, how can i get a json string with multiple Folders and Files.??
Help me

```
public class Folders2
{
}

public class Assets
{
}

public class Folder2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Folders2 folders { get; set; }
    public Assets assets { get; set; }
}

public class Folders
{
    public Folder2 folder { get; set; }
}

public class UploadedFile
{
    public string content_type { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string file_data { get; set; }
}

public class Asset
{
    public int folder_id { get; set; }
    public UploadedFile uploaded_file { get; set; }
}

public class Assets2
{
    public Asset asset { get; set; }
}

public class Folder
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Folders folders { get; set; }
    public Assets2 assets { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Folder folder { get; set; }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I tried working on this getting Directories and Files in a List,
Can anyone tell me how to parse this like above json string

```
List<string> li = new List<string>();               
li.Add(path);            
foreach (string files in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
            bool exists2 = li.Exists(element => element.StartsWith(files));
            if (exists2 == false)
            {
                li.Add(files);
            }                    
        }             

        foreach (string Folder in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {                   
                li.Add(Folder);                                        

            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {                       
                bool exists = li.Exists(element => element.StartsWith(file));                     
                if (exists==false)
                {
                    li.Add(file);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can someone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help and effort from Fredrik M , I have achieved my desired task
public class FolderRoot1
    {

```
    public FolderSJ folder { get; set; }
}

public class FolderSJ
{
    public FolderSJ()
    {
        assets =new List<AssetRoot> { };
        folders = new List<FolderRoot1> { };

    }


    public string parent_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<AssetRoot> assets { get; set; }
    public List<FolderRoot1> folders { get; set; }

}

public class AssetSJ
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string content_type { get; set; }
    public string file_data { get; set; }
}
public class AssetRoot
{
    public UploadedFileContent asset { get; set; }
}
public class UploadedFileContent
{       
    public AssetSJ uploaded_file { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see two ways to create your JSON-string from the object.

1. ) You manually create the json-string with iterateing through the object and its properties.
2. ) Use for IE. JSON.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) Serialize your object to json.

But I think you also should rethink the design of the classes, but thats an other thing.

Comment: Any idea or creating it manually, I have tried creating a List of Folders and Files but it doesnt works out.

Comment: What exactly ain't working for you? Doesn't it get encoded to json or is it the look of the json string that is bad?

Comment: It is the look of the Json string.  List returns an array []  , but i need an object to parse.

Comment: I need objects delimeters '{}' not '[]'  and folders if contain subfolder then  "folders": {
                 "folder": {
                    "name": "child abcd"
/////////////////////

{
  "folder": {
    "name": "abc",
    "assets": [
      {
        "asset": {
          "folder_id": 1,
          "uploaded_file": {
            "filename": "settings.png",
            "content_type": "application/png",
            "file_data": "dsadsad"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "folders": [
      {
        "name": "child abc",
        "assets": [],
        "folders": []
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: How can i add , folder within folders
"folders": {
                 "folder": {
                    "name": "child abcd"
                           }          
                           },

Comment: Do not forget, that many folder under say property "folders" will be an array of objects. In that meaning would property folders be

"folders" : [{ "folder": { "name" : "value" }  }, { "folder": { "name" : "value" }  }]